# Recibir variables enviadas en HTML desde un WebView en React Native

Tags: javascript, variables, react-native, variables-globales

Estoy desarrollando una App que necesita enviar variables a una pagina html que se mostrará en un WebView. A continuación dejo un ejemplo básico del código de la Aplicación React Native.

`

```
export default class App extends Component {


  render()
  {

   let variableCadena="React Native";




    return(

      <Container>
        <WebView
        style={{flex: 1}}
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        source={{uri:'file:///android_asset/PaginaEjemplo.html'}}
         style={{ marginTop: 20 }}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        domStorageEnabled={true}
        allowFileAccess={true}
        allowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs={true}
        injectedJavaScript={variableCadena} 
        >

      </WebView>      
      </Container>
    );
  }
};
```

`

La página web por su parte puede ser tan sencilla como la siguiente.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Ejemplo de inyeccion desde React Native</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var variable = variableCadena;
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    document.body.innerHTML = "<h1>La variable es:"
    +variable+ "</h1>"

   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

`

El resultado que se espera es que la página web muestre en las etiquetas h1 el texto React Native que se definió en la aplicación. Gracias a todos por sus sugerencias.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar la funcion postMessage y `EventListener` "messsage".

Por ejemplo, en tu html puedes tener un:

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener("message", function(data) {
    alert(data.data);
  });
</script>
```

Y en tu webview puedes tener un:

```
<script>
  window.postMessage("Envar info a WebView");
</script>
```

Puedes encontrar mas informacion en https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview#onmessage

Comment: Gracias por tu sugerencia. No me queda muy claro el ejemplo. Lo he intentado pero sin éxito. ¿Tienes idea de si pudiera lograr el objetivo de obtener en la página web la variable que se tiene en la App. ? ¿Podrías proporcionar un código  más explícito reutilizando el mismo código que muestro a manera de ejemplo? He intentado lograr obtener el valor de la variable haciendo uso de las propiedades injectJavascript e injectedJavaScript y también en la propiedad source con las propiedades method y headers y body. Tampoco he logrado obtener la solución.